# The flow of Harmonic vector fields

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, harmonic-functions

A  map or  a  vector  field  $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is  called  a  harmonic  map if all its  components  are  harmonic  functions.

Motivated  by  conversations on [this  questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269940/vector-field-with-holomorphic-flow) we ask:

> Is  the  flow  of a  Harmonic  vector  field  on $\mathbb{R}^n$, a  harmonic function?

More  precisely, assume  that every  component  of  the  vector  field $x'=f(x)$ is  a  harmonic  map.  Is  it  true to say that for  every  $t$,  $\phi_t$ is  a  Harmonic map?
Note  that  the  converse is  true. Namely, a  vector  field  is  Harmonic if  its  flow  is  harmonic.

Comment: No. Try some simple cases for which you can solve the differential equations explicitly.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy   yes thank you $(y^2_x^2)\partial_x$ is a counter example.but the converse is true, i think. This is a motivation to modify this post to have a true version.

Comment: As stated, the answer to your question is no for a trivial reason. *Any* diffeomorphism $\phi_0$ can be extended to a flow along a vector field $V$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a "known true version", but it is basically what you have already as the converse.

**Defn** Let $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ be Riemannian manifolds, and let $\phi: M\to N$ be a smooth mapping. The *tension field* of $\phi$ is defined to be
$$ \tau(\phi) = \mathrm{trace}_g D \mathrm{d}\phi $$
where $D$ is the pull-back of the Levi-Civita connection on $N$ to $M$ via $\phi$.

**Defn** A mapping $\phi:M\to N$ is said to be "harmonic" if $\tau(\phi) \equiv 0$.

**Rmk** In the case $M$ and $N$ are Euclidean spaces, this reduces to the components of mapping being harmonic functions.

**Defn** Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, a vector field is said to be 1-harmonic-Killing if, denoting by $\varphi_t$ its corresponding one parameter family of diffeomorphisms, that
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \tau(\varphi_t) \Big|_{t = 0} = 0 $$

**Rmk** $\tau(\varphi_0) = \tau(\mathrm{id}) = 0$. So the definition of 1-harmonic-Killing asks that the flow to be linearly harmonic.

**Thm** A vector field $V$ is 1-harmonic-Killing if and only if 
$$ \triangle X^\flat = \mathrm{Ric}(X,\cdot) \tag{1}$$
where $\triangle$ is the Hodge-Laplacian and $\mathrm{Ric}$ is the Ricci tensor.

**Rmk** In the Euclidean case, Ricci curvature vanishes, and (1) reduces to what you state as "harmonic vector field".

---

This result can be found in: [Dodson, Trinidad Pérez, and Vázquez-Abal](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2016229); [Stepanov and Shandra](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1996772); and [Nouhaud](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=290289). The first reference also contains examples showing that there exists 1-harmonic-Killing vector fields whose flow is not always harmonic.

Notice however, Remark 3.1 and Proposition 3.1 in the first-cited paper above, which combine to say that *on a compact Riemannian manifold with non-positive Ricci curvature, a vector field $V$ is 1-harmonic-Killing if and only if $V$ is a parallel vector field*. In particular, this implies that on such manifolds any 1-harmonic-Killing vector field will give rise to a harmonic flow. While this statement gives a positive answer to your question, we should note that in this setting $V$ is also necessarily Killing and hence the flow generated is a one parameter family of isometries, and hence the result can also be viewed as a rigidity statement.

---

A geometrically interesting fact is this:

Let $V$ be a vector field and $\varphi_t$ its local one parameter family of isometries. In the above we asked about the property of $\varphi_t$ being harmonic. If we replace the word harmonic by

- isometric; we get Killing vector fields;
- conformal isometric: we get conformal Killing vector fields;
- totally geodesic: we get affine Killing vector fields.

In all three of the above situations, having the "1-" version hold (meaning that the condition holds for $\varphi_t$ to first order as $t \to 0$) implies that the condition in fact holds (to infinite order). So in the literature we do not distinguish between 1-Killing vector fields and Killing vector fields.

One reason behind this distinction is the fact that *compositions of harmonic maps need not be harmonic*, in contrast to the other three cases mentioned above.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your  very helpful  answer. I learn a lot  from your answer.