# Vector field with Harmonic flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Assume  that $(M,g)$  is  a  Riemannian  manifold. A  vector  field $X$ on  $M$ is  called  a  harmonic vector  field  if  the corresponding $1$-form   $\alpha$  with $\alpha(Y)= \langle X,Y \rangle_g$  is  a  harmonic  $1$-form.

Motivated  by [this  conversations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269940/vector-field-with-holomorphic-flow/269971#269971) we  ask the  following  question:

> Assume  that $X$  is a  vector  field on  $M$. Assume  that for  every  $t$  the  flow $\phi_t$ of the  vector  field is  a harmonic  map. Does  this  imply that the  vector  field  is  a  harmonic  vector  field?

Comment: It appears to me that this can be resolved by a straightforward calculation. Did you try that already? $X$ satisfies the linearized harmonic map equation. Either that matches or there is an extra curvature term.

Comment: @DeaneYang  I  just  tried  for  Euclidean structure.

Comment: May  you  elaborate  your  comment?

Comment: Differentiate $\Delta \phi_t = 0$ with respect to $t$. Compare it to the equator for a harmonic vector field.

Comment: [My answer to your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270212/3948) already contains the answer. The answer is that the corresponding one form solves $\triangle \alpha = \mathrm{Ric}(X,\cdot)$ (with an extra curvature term as @DeaneYang suspects), and so is guaranteed harmonic only in the case $M$ is Ricci flat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, right away, you can see that the answer is 'no', in general.  Consider the round $n$-sphere $S^n$ with its standard metric.  When $n>1$, it has no nonzero harmonic $1$-forms, but it has nontrivial Killing vector fields since it is a homogeneous Riemannian manifold.  Since the flow $\phi_t$ of such a Killing field $X$ is a harmonic map of $S^n$ to itself, this example shows that the flow of $X$ can be harmonic even though $X$ is not.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your  interesting   answer.